# "java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException" error in Java

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm writing a simple Java code and I'm getting this error after entering the first input:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0
at university.GetStudentSpect(university.java:26)
at university.main(university.java:11)
```

Code:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
public class university {
    public static Scanner Reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static int n;
    public static int m=0;
    public static int l;
    public static StringBuilder SConverter = new StringBuilder();
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GetStudentsNumber();
        GetStudentSpect();
    }

    public static void GetStudentsNumber() {
        System.out.println("enter the number of students");
        n = Reader.nextInt();
    }
    public static String [][] StudentSpect = new String [n][2];

    public static void GetStudentSpect() {
        for (int i=0;i<n;i++) {
            System.out.println("enter the name of the student");
            StudentSpect[i][0] = SConverter.append(Reader.nextInt()).toString();
            System.out.println("enter the id of the student");
            StudentSpect[i][1] = SConverter.append(Reader.nextInt()).toString();
            System.out.println("enter the number of courses of the student");
            l = Reader.nextInt();
            m += l;
            StudentSpect[i][2] = SConverter.append(l).toString();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static code gets executed when the class is first loaded. That means, you initialize `StudentSpec` before your `main` method runs. That in turn means that `n` is not assigned a value yet, so it defaults to 0. Because of that, `StudentSpec` is an array of dimensions zero by two. (Note that it does not matter whether you put the code to initialize `StudentSpec` with all the other variables or later in the class, all static stuff gets initialized first.)

Then your code in `main` runs, calling `GetStudentsNumber`, which sets `n`, but does not initialize `StudentSpec` (again).  Then `GetStudentSpect` runs, and as soon as you try to access `StudentSpec`, your program crashes, as it's an array with zero elements.

To fix this, initialize `StudentSpec` in `GetStudentsNumber` after reading `n`, i.e., move the code from the static initializer to this method.

Comment: I tried to do that at the beginning but it gave this error:illegal modifier for parameter StudentSpect;only final is permitted

Comment: I fixed this error too according to : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29086903/how-to-create-public-array-accessible-by-all-methods-but-have-user-input-determ    .it was really helpful thank you ❤❤❤

Answer (score 0):

Array Index start with 0 and you have given size 2 means it can only have positions 0 and 1 
not 2.

````
 public static String [][] StudentSpect = new String [n][2];
```
And you are accessing array position of 2 over here.
```
 StudentSpect[i][2] = SConverter.append(l).toString();
```
So make this Change
````

public static String [][] StudentSpect = new String [n][3];

Comment: You have inittialized StudentSpect  before getting n variable initalied

Comment: Declare this on top public static String [][] StudentSpect;

Comment: initialize after n is initialized like this :- StudentSpect = new String [n][3];

Comment: Thanks for helping out 